# How to avoid composer discard changes message

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm updating symfony verdors via composer. I always do it using:

```
php composer.phar update
```

But recent version of composer, before update each package show a message like this:

```
  - Updating doctrine/data-fixtures dev-master (a95d783 => a28b6bd)
The package has modified files:
M .gitignore
M .gitmodules
M LICENSE
M README.md
M UPGRADE
M composer.json
M lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/AbstractFixture.php
M lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/DependentFixtureInterface.php
M lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Event/Listener/MongoDBReferenceListener.php
M lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Event/Listener/ORMReferenceListener.php
```

-10 more files modified, choose "v" to view the full list
    Discard changes [y,n,v,s,?]?

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Set composer config to discard changes
(see: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1188):

```
php composer.phar config --global discard-changes true
```

Answer (score 34):

both @lemats and @reza-sanaie's answers are incomplete as --no-interaction (-n) composer's option is required to have a real update without any question (see https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1188#issuecomment-16011533).

So after

```
php composer.phar config --global discard-changes true
```

or after modifying composer.json

```
"config": {
    "discard-changes": true
},
```

use

```
php composer.phar update -n
```

Answer (score 22):

Alternative to @lemats solution you can modify the composer.json file with:

```
  "config": {
      "discard-changes": true
  },
```

It's worth nothing for this option to kick in you have to be running in `--no-interaction` mode

`php composer.json install --no-interaction`

Although I agree with @Seldaek on you shouldn't be modifying these vendor files, but sometimes you are forced to monkey patch it :(

Comment: You could always do a pull request to the vendor repo if it is an important fix

Answer (score -4):

How about not modifying vendor files? If they get modified most likely it's because of some messed up git settings for the line endings. See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: still happens sometimes. I've seen people with servers that chmod on crontab that mess with the perms of all the vendors. or when debugging a vendor lib, it can happen too

Comment: This can also happen because of git filemode, especially when the vendor file is something you have symlinked in bin.

Comment: And bug testing, sometimes you need to var dump in the vendor files to see what on earth is going on... and you may not always put the changes back 'exactly' as they were... maybe a space is added etc.

Comment: some projects (e.g . Drupal 9.x) modify both checkout files and vendor files,  it can't always be avoided.